# Python type error: unbound method dict.keys() needs an argument

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments, typeerror, cirq

I am trying to access the keys in my results_dict dictionary with an if statment in my _run method. Specifically I get the TypeError: unbound method dict.keys() needs an argument error on the `if (gate.key) in results_dict.keys():` line. I tried just running `print(results_dict.keys())` and I get the same TypeError: unbound method dict.keys() needs an argument error I am not sure why I am getting this error.

```
import cirq
from typing import Dict
from collections import defaultdict
from cirq.sim.simulator import SimulatesSamples
from cirq import ops, protocols
from cirq.study.resolver import ParamResolver
from cirq.circuits.circuit import AbstractCircuit
import numpy as np

def _run(
        circuit: 'AbstractCircuit',
        param_resolver: 'ParamResolver',
        repetitions: int,
    ) -> Dict[str, np.ndarray]:

        results_dict = Dict[str, Dict[str, np.ndarray]]
        values_dict: Dict[cirq.Qid,  int] = defaultdict(int)
        param_resolver = param_resolver or ParamResolver({})
        resolved_circuit = protocols.resolve_parameters(circuit, param_resolver)

        for moment in resolved_circuit:
            for op in moment:
                gate = op.gate

                if isinstance(gate, ops.XPowGate) and gate.exponent == 1:
                    values_dict[op.qubits[0]] = 1 - values_dict[op.qubits[0]]

                elif isinstance(gate, ops.MeasurementGate):
                    qubits_in_order = op.qubits
                    if (gate.key) in results_dict.keys():
                        shape = len(qubits_in_order)
                        current_array = results_dict[gate.key]
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect `results_dict = Dict[str, Dict[str, np.ndarray]]` to do? `results_dict` is assigned a type, not an actual dict. Compare that line to the line below

Comment: `typing.Dict` is for type hints, not creating an actual `dict` object, and has been deprecated since Python 3.9 because `dict` itself can be used wherever `Dict` was previously needed.

Comment: At runtime, `Dict[...]` simply evaluates to `dict`, as if you had written `results_dict = dict`. You want something like `results_dict: dict[str, dict[str, np.ndarray]] = {}`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create a `dict` object; you just defined an alias for a particular type hint. Instead, use

```
results_dict: dict[str, dict[str, np.ndarray]] = {}
```

(`typing.Dict` has been deprecated since Python 3.9 in favor of `dict` itself.)